# Why is React Webpack production build showing Blank page?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, reactjs, webpack, redux

I'm building a react app, and at the moment `webpack-dev-server` works just fine( the **hello world** text shows up ), But webpack -p shows blank page. For the Production build The network tab under chrome dev tools, shows `index.html` and `index_bundle.js` to have size 0 B(see picture)[image] But That is clearly not the case HTML file size is 227 B & `index_bundle.js` file size is 195Kb(see picture) [image]

Also Chrome Devtools Elements Tab shows the following(see picture)
[image]

My webpack config file looks like this:[image]

Comment: What does your production config look like for webpack?  json stringify the configuration.

Comment: added a screen capture of the webpack config

Comment: If you look at the difference between the development/production configuration you will see that only the development configuration contains the `devServer` node.  You may need to consider adding an additional environment argument that indicates you wish to do production based hosting and then inject the devServer node accordingly.

Comment: To prove this point copy the `devServer` node into the `productionConfig`.

Comment: I copied the devserver to the productionConfig right above the plugins, and yet still the same result

Comment: Sorry, just stabbing at this, but you may need to copy the `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` across to your production config too.

Comment: Again, I must not that if this works all it serves is to prove that you can get it work. I do recommend you add another env flag to enable/disable this feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113437/discussion-between-ctrlplusb-and-jasan).

Comment: I was using browser history in my routes config  file, once i changed that to hashHistory the production build is working. WHy is that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figured it out, I was using browserHistory without setting up a local server. If i changed it to hashHistory it worked. To test webpack production locally with react-router browser history i needed to do this Configure a Server:

Your server must be ready to handle real URLs. When the app first loads at / it will probably work, but as the user navigates around and then hits refresh at /accounts/23 your web server will get a request to /accounts/23. You will need it to handle that URL and include your JavaScript application in the response.

An express app might look like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
const app = express()

// serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

// handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
// a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("server started on port " + port)
```

And just in case anyone is deploying to firebase using react-router with browser-history do this:

```
{
  "firebase": "<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>",
  "public": "<YOUR-PUBLIC-DIRECTORY>",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: but there is a problem - my index.html load css files, bundle.js - and the server attempts to load it via "*" route - and as result - in the browser rendered nothing. How can I fix that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So in this example you use hash history? or browser history thanks in advance.  I am having the same problem

Comment: @PeakSornpaisarn in this example i'm using browser history.

Comment: This worked for me! `import {HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'` instead of `import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'`. I'm trying to deploy a React.js site on Swarm and after several hours, the hash router was the only way I could get it to work!

Answer (score 10):

use

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

instead of

```
import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and don't forget to replace it in your routes code

```
<HashRouter>
  ...
</HashRouter>
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing

`import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'`

to:

`import {HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'`

in **App.js** helped me fix the same issue in my create-react-app project.

Comment: not a good solution, mainly when auth libraries are present.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub Pages doesn’t support routers that use the HTML5 `pushState` history API under the hood (for example, React Router using `browserHistory`). This is because when there is a fresh page load for a url like `http://user.github.io/todomvc/todos/42`, where `/todos/42` is a frontend route, the GitHub Pages server returns 404 because it knows nothing of `/todos/42`. If you want to add a router to a project hosted on GitHub Pages, here are a couple of solutions:

- You could switch from using HTML5 history API to routing with hashes. 
  If you use React Router, you can switch to `hashHistory` for this effect, but the URL will be longer and more verbose (for example, `http://user.github.io/todomvc/#/todos/42?_k=yknaj`). [Read more](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) about different history implementations in React Router.
- Alternatively, you can use a trick to teach GitHub Pages to handle 404 by redirecting to your `index.html` page with a special redirect parameter. You would need to add a `404.html` file with the redirection code to the `build` folder before deploying your project, and you’ll need to add code handling the redirect parameter to `index.html`. You can find a detailed explanation of this technique [in this guide](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages).

Answer (score 2):

```js
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar" />
<Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
```

> **basename**: string
>   The base URL for all locations. If your app is served from a sub-directory on your server, you’ll want to set this to the sub-directory. A properly formatted basename should have a leading slash, but no trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me my error was because I mixed up folders

Solution:

```
npm run build
```

my apache config:

***did not work***

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/example.com/client/public/
```

***worked (build folder not public)***

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/example.com/client/build/
```

Comment: This saved a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

I had a unique solution - only one page was not running for me. So I just inspected the console log and found the error. For some reason, the error was only displaying for "react-scripts-build", not "react-scripts-start".

This resulted in a blank page