# React production shows blank page

Tags: reactjs, webpack

i have a problem with a webpack build, the command i run is

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.prod.js
```

and the file webpack prod is:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var path = require('path');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), '/public'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js'
},

plugins: [
    //new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        mangle: {
            keep_fnames: true,
            except: ['$super']
        }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    })
  ]
});
```

webpack.common.js is

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');
var pkgBower = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {

entry: {
  'app': './main.js'
},

resolve: {
  root: path.join(__dirname, ''),
  modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},

module: {
  loaders: [...]
},

devServer: {
  outputPath: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
},

plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? 'index.html' : 'index.prod.html',
      baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? '/' : '/'
  })      
  ]
};
```

i can run the build but unfortunatelly when i open index.html it shows a blank page to me, i want to include this SPA in a spring boot project but I do not know how ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved! was a problem of "browserHistory"

If you use the "browserHistory" as history manager your webpack needs a node.js  server to run, using a "hashHistory" you can use it as a normal web page!

See
[Why is React Webpack production build showing Blank page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550560/why-is-react-webpack-production-build-showing-blank-page)

Answer (score 1):

First things first, which version of webpack are you using Lorenzo? Probably due to syntax, it's 1.X.

First, check in your package.json file which version is. Then, if it's really 1.x you can build in debug mode.

```
export default {
    entry: [
        './src/Client.js'
    ],
    debug: true
}
```

Inside your webpack.common.js

Check the error, paste here.

I hope it helps, welcome to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), here are a few notes that can improve our community =)

Comment: Hi Yuri, i am using the version 1.14

Comment: enable debug mode then.

Comment: I changed my webpack.common like this
       module.exports = {

        entry: {
          'app': './main.js',
        },
 debug:true, }

And i did not catch any error

Answer (score 0):

Try to put "main":"index.js" in package.json file
That solved my problem.

```
  "main": "index.js",

  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
```

Happy to help.