# White page deploying react app with webpack in IIS Server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, iis, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to deploy a react web application based in microfrontends using ModuleFederationPlugin and webpack, but when I try to deploy one of microfrontends in isolation I get a white page without errors.

**My webpack configuration to production:**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin')
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common')
const packageJson = require('../package.json')

const prodConfig = {
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        publicPath: '/Microfrontends/marketing/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: 'marketing',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            exposes: {
                './MarketingModule': './src/bootstrap'
            },
            shared: packageJson.dependencies
        })
    ]
}

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, prodConfig)
```

**My webpack common with babel:**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

**My App.js component with React-Router:**

```
export default function App({ history }) {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/Microfrontends/marketing/pricing" component={Pricing} />
                        <Route path="/Microfrontends/marketing/" component={Landing} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </StylesProvider>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

When I deploy in server all status requests are 200 and the chrome console hasn't errors

Comment: This link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550560/why-is-react-webpack-production-build-showing-blank-page

Comment: I tried all of suggestions but none of these worked for me

Comment: Check the browser’s console for errors,
Does the app link to the wrong bundle?
Update the “homepage” setting in your package.json,
Build your app again and put it on your web space.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding or changing the homepage attribute in the package.json file.
Set it to be relative to the path by using `homepage: '.';`.

If you still get a white page after doing this it may be that the basename for your Router is not set:

```
<Router basename='/name' history={history}>
   <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/Microfrontends/marketing/pricing" component={Pricing} />
       <Route path="/Microfrontends/marketing/" component={Landing} />
   </Switch>
</Router>
```